# Is it possible to force Oracle to apply View Merging in query with User Defined Views and Functions?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, query-performance

The problem is that - I am forced to use View instead of Table (this is the 1st case in the below list).

1. I run the query on View with Function in Where clause as a user that is not owner of those Objects (View and Function):

```
select count(*) from VW_BOOK b where contains(b.title, fn_textconverter('Eden'), 1) > 0;
```

or

```
select count(*) from VW_BOOK b where contains(b.title, (select fn_textconverter('Eden') from dual), 1) > 0;
```

So, the above queries are very slow because Oracle optimizer ignores indexes in Table and pushes predicates into View.

2. When I run the same query but instead of using View I use Table, it executes very fast and applies indexes created for table:

```
select count(*) from TB_BOOK b where contains(b.title, fn_textconverter('Eden'), 1) > 0;
```

3. The same good result I see for the the query when I use View, but instead of function I put the result of function without calling the function itself:

```
select count(*) from VW_BOOK b where contains(b.title, '\E\d\e\n%', 1) > 0;
```

When I try setting optimizer_secure_view_merging to False or granting to my user MERGE VIEW privilege, the 1st case from the above list executes very fast bypassing pushing predicates into View.
As I cannot add additional privileges to user because of policy and cannot change Oracle parameters as well, questions arise:

Is it possible to force Oracle to merge User Defined Views and Functions regardless of whether I have set optimizer_secure_view_merging parameter as TRUE and do not have privilege MERGE VIEW?

**Maybe there are ways to set or recreate function as "Secured", so Oracle could safely merge it with my View?**

Comment: Can you create a pass-through version of `fn_textconverter` in the same schema as `VW_BOOK`?  If the function is in the same schema it should  automatically trusted for view merging, even it it calls functions in other schemas.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, actually all the objects are on the same schema. The only thing is that I should login as another user and after I login triggered logon trigger which changes "current_schema" parameter to the schema which owns all the objects.

Comment: And why can't you `GRANT MERGE VIEW ON VW_BOOK TO` the user you log in as?  But I am starting to see the point of your question...

Comment: Such policy requirments. Non extra privileges can be granted to my application user.

Comment: How about to `PUBLIC`?  That would also work.  Otherwise, I am afraid the answer to your question is "no".  You may be able to workaround it like `WITH input (txt) AS ( SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE fn_textconverter('Eden') FROM DUAL) SELECT ... FROM VW_BOOK, INPUT WHERE contains(b.title, input.txt), 1) > 0` or similar.  Sorry.  Kudos for a really interesting question though. Thank you for that.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, I suspect PUBLIC user also cannot be granted that privilege. The approach with MATERIALIZE hint also didn't give performance improvement. Nevertheless, thank you for taking the time and effort in suggesting different options.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with security, but if `fn_textconverter('Eden')` will always equal `\E\d\e\n%` every time it runs, try creating function `fn_textconverter` as deterministic, so Oracle knows it does not have to re-evaluate it for every row.

I.e.,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_textconverter 
    ( p_in VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you're probably right. My function is deterministic and it can speed up in some cases, but not in my case. I tried setting my function as deterministic, however nothing changed. I think, it has to do with security. As I already said, after setting the value of Oracle parameter optimizer_secure_view_merging to false, my request reponds instantly, since I see from the execution plan that in that case existent index from source table is used.